# Pythonic way to generate sequence from linear difference

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sequence

I have a sequence definition

*x<sub>n+1</sub>* = *f*(*x<sub>n</sub>* , *x<sub>n-1</sub>*)

Where *x<sub>n</sub>* is *x* evaluated at time *t<sub>n</sub>*. Any value in the sequence is defined by some function of the previous two values (and the time step, but for now that's constant). I would like to generate the first *N* values in this sequence, given *x<sub>0</sub>* & *x<sub>1</sub>*.

What's the most pythonic way to do this?

My current approach is just to loop. I create a `numpy.ones` array of the correct size, then loop through it by index. If index = `0` or `1` then I change the value from `1` to *x<sub>0</sub>* / *x<sub>1</sub>* respectively. For greater indecies I lookup the previous values in the array and apply the function.

But I feel like this doesn't seem to be making use of the numpy array methods, so I wonder if there's a better approach?

#### Code

In my code I have a `createSequence` function, which takes in a definition of *x<sub>n+1</sub>* as well as boundary conditions and timestep, and outputs a sequence following those rules. NB, I'm very new to Python so any general advice would also be appreciated!

```
import numpy as np

def x_next(x_current,x_previous,dt):
    """Function to return the next value in the sequence
       x_current and x_previous are the values at tn and tn-1 respectively
       dt is the time step
    """
    return (x_current - x_previous)/dt #as an example

def createSequence(x_next,x0,x1,start,stop,dt):
    """ Function to create sequence based on x_next function, and boundary conditions"""
    num = (stop-start)/dt
    x_array = np.ones(int(num))
    x_array[0] = x0
    x_array[1] = x1
    for index in range(len(x_array)):
        if index == 0:
            x_array[index] = x0
        elif index == 1:
            x_array[index] = x1
        else:
            x_current = x_array[index - 1]
            x_previous = x_array[index - 2]
            x_array[index] = x_next(x_current,x_previous,dt)
    return x_array

print(createSequence(x_next=x_next,x0=0.1,x1=0.2,start=0,stop=20,dt=0.1))
```

Comment: Show your working loopy code?

Comment: @Divakar I have added it. I've included an example definition of the sequence, my actual sequence takes in a few more constant parameters, but otherwise is very similar

Comment: Would cached Recursion be a solution?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Well in reality I'm graphing it, but there's a `print` with some initial conditions so that the code actually does something!

Comment: do the initialization of `x_array` before the loop - right now you are repeating the startup tests for every step

Comment: there are descrete time tools in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html  also https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html#numpy.apply_along_axis looks applicable

Comment: If the recurrence function is linear, you can use [`scipy.signal.lfilter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a generator because

- it allows you to generate sequences of arbitrary length without wasting memory
- one might argue it is "pythonic".

In the following, I will use the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) as an example because it takes a similar form to your problem.

```
def fibonacci(a=0, b=1, length=None):
    # Generate a finite or infinite sequence
    num = 0
    while length is None or num < length:
        # Evaluate the next Fibonacci number
        c = a + b
        yield c
        # Advance to the next item in the sequence
        a, b = c, a
        num += 1
```

Note that `a` corresponds to your `x_n`, `b` corresponds to `x_{n-1}`, and `c` corresponds to `x_{n+1}`. And a simple example:

```
>>> list(fibonacci(length=10))
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

If you want to get the sequence into a numpy array

```
>>> np.fromiter(fibonacci(length=10), int)
array([ 1,  1,  2,  3,  5,  8, 13, 21, 34, 55])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the initial collection of terms. However, if it should happen that you, or anyone reading this question, might want individual terms then the [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) library comes in handy. Everything here up to the horizontal line is from [Solve a recurrence relation](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Quick-examples#solve-a-recurrence-relation).

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('y')
y
>>> var('n', integer=True)
n
>>> f = Function('f')
>>> f = y(n)-2*y(n-1)-5*y(n-2)
>>> r = rsolve(f, y(n), [1, 4])
```

---

Once you have `r` you can either evaluate it for various values of `n` within the sympy facilities ...

```
>>> N(r.subs(n,1))
4.00000000000000
>>> N(r.subs(n,2))
13.0000000000000
>>> N(r.subs(n,10))
265333.000000000
```

Or you could 'lift' the code in `r` and re-use it for your own routines.

```
>>> r
(1/2 + sqrt(6)/4)*(1 + sqrt(6))**n + (-sqrt(6) + 1)**n*(-sqrt(6)/4 + 1/2)
```